# C/C++ programs under YARN

Tags: c++, c, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is there way to run native C/C++ applications under YARN? I googled a lot and it seems it should be possible, but I failed to find any POC or instruction.

Comment: Any ideas on where I can find some clues?

Answer (score 1):

There are some early implementations of C++ MR API, please take a look at [MAPREDUCE-1270](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-1270) and [MAPREDUCE-2841](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2841)

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is running any native C/C++ application in YARN container. So, wonder if there is any wrapper or complementary service around YARN.